# Elasticsearch expected behavior when aggregating on numeric array field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an aggregate query, binning my data into histogram buckets based on the values in a numeric array field. The array will almost always have length 1, but I cannot guarantee it.
What is the expected behavior when binning like this on a field that is an array.

I understand that if this query is a must have, we may have to modify the schema, but would still like to understand how elastic will behave here.

Example document:

```
    {
      "begin": "100",
      "total": 20,
      "fractions": [ 10 ]
    }
```

Example query:

```
GET /index-2/_search
{
  "size": 10, 
  "aggs": {
    "buckets": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "begin",
        "interval": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "fractions": {
          "histogram": {
            "field": "fractions",
            "interval": 10
          }
        }
        "totals": {
          "histogram": {
            "field": "totals",
            "interval": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get no errors when running this query on 4 to 5 million documents. Example response snippet below:

```
"aggregations": {
  "buckets": {
    "buckets": [
    {
      "key": 0,
      "doc_count": 1235,
      "fractions": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": 0,
            "doc_count": 402
          },
          {
            "key": 10,
            "doc_count": 176
          },

          ...

          {
            "key": 480,
            "doc_count": 0
          },
          {
            "key": 490,
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      "totals": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": 0,
            "doc_count": 271
          },
          {
            "key": 10,
            "doc_count": 117
          },

          ...

          {
            "key": 550,
            "doc_count": 0
          },
          {
            "key": 560,
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei. If I want my aggregation to only take account of the first value in the array, is that possible without changing the schema?

Comment: I found that I can limit to the first item of the array using script. Instead of 
`"field": "fractions",` you can use `"script" : "doc['fractions'][0]",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values from the array will help creating buckets for that interval. If the documents that matched the query have `fractions` values as `10, 50, 90, 100` and if one of those documents has `[10, 20, 150]` as `fractions` then those values will basically increase the list of terms that makes out the array of "available" values for the buckets. The `fractions` aggregation will cover all the buckets from `10` to `150`.

For example, a document like `{"begin":100,"total":20,"fractions":[10,35,55]}` with an aggregation like `"fractions": {"histogram": {"field": "fractions", interval": 5}}` will generate an aggregation result like

```
           "fractions": {
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": 10,
                    "doc_count": 1
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 15,
                    "doc_count": 0
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 20,
                    "doc_count": 0
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 25,
                    "doc_count": 0
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 30,
                    "doc_count": 0
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 35,
                    "doc_count": 1
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 40,
                    "doc_count": 0
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 45,
                    "doc_count": 0
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 50,
                    "doc_count": 0
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 55,
                    "doc_count": 1
                 }
              ]
           }
```

Basically, the list of values is just an additional set of terms in the aggregation set.